# CSS content:'audio/video file path' not supported

Tags: css, audio, video

How to specify an **audio/video** file in CSS `content` property?

The content supports an image file as-

```
<div style="content:url('1.jpg');"></div>
```

This works fine. But in place of **img1.jpg** it doesn't support audio/video files by default.

Is it possible at all by setting CSS content property or do I need anything more to set???

Comment: You can't put HTML in the `content` property...frankly I'm surprised you say that the image is 'working'.

Comment: I did and it didn't work. Perhaps you could make a JSFiddle to demonstrate. Ahh...I see you have updated your OP and comment

Comment: @Paulie_D Try it with the code i have given.

Answer (score 1):

Basically,the `content` property should only be used on pseudo-elements and not `div` etc. so you are attempting to use it incorrectly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

If you want to put an image in the div...just do it. Ditto for other media.

Comment: My question was the `content: url('path')` works for images but not for audio/video not even for html files. How to make it work???

Comment: You can't...that's not what it's for.

Comment: For `<div>` it is working perfectly with images only.

Comment: It may render but it's not correct HTML/CSS. Is there a reason you can't just put the image in the div?

Comment: Why isn't it supporting HTML even as it proposes-
`content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html)`

Comment: A url isn't HTML as such...its a value...sort of. Read the spec I linked to,